# Most efficient way to add menu items to a tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating an food menu app in Xcode using Swift and I am trying to find the most appropriate way to code the food information for my prototype cell to display.  Each foodItem will have 3 attributes associated with it: the name of the food, a description of the food, and a price.  Would it be best to create a Food object from a class, add them all to an array, and iterate through the array using the indexPath? Do the exact same thing but with a struct (what I'm leaning towards), or even add the food items to a tuple and iterate over that? Each scene will be responsible for displaying around 20 foodItem cells.  There will be 5 scenes: Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Dessert, Beverages.

[image: prototype cell showing food item attributes]

Comment: I don't know why you are saying "iterate". To display the data you don't iterate directly, you simply return the cell requested in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It isn't really a question of efficiciency either, but usability. All 3 methods will involve memory access and an array, so equivalent access overhead. If you don't need additional methods the a struct is ok although structure are passed by value so you need to factor that in. If you need to pass by reference or you need additional methods then a class is needed.

Comment: If you are not using CoreData and can use structs, then I would suggest that. Then your data is immutable and in a way safer to use. Safer in that it won't change on you in unexpected ways  at unexpected times due to Swift's value type semantics.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do outlets for the table view cell labels. These outlets have to be stored in a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.
Then you should make a class for the food with the properties you need.  Then implement `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` in your view controller. All the food items you could 'pack' into an array. Then in `tableView_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can do:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as YourCustomCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    }
cell.foodName = "noodles"
cell.foodPrice = "12,95$"
```